# Minimizing variable copies in recursive function

Tags: c++

I'm looking for efficient memory allocation when dealing with recursive function. As far as I understand, variables I use in the function will remain allocated in memory until recursion is finished. Is there a way to avoid this as I believe this causes slow run of my code below where state variable is copied every time the function is called (correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to C++).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int N = 30;
double MIN_COST = 1000000;
vector<int> MIN_CUT = {};


void minCut(vector<int> state, int index, int nodeValue) {
    double currentCost;

    if (index >= 0) {
        currentCost = getCurrentCost(state); // some magic evaluating state cost
        state.push_back(nodeValue);
        if (currentCost >= MIN_COST) {    // kill branch if incomplete solution is already worse than best achieved solution
            return;
        }
    }

    if (index == N - 1) {   // check if leaf node
        if (currentCost < MIN_COST) {
            MIN_COST = currentCost;
            MIN_CUT = state;
        }
        return;
    }

    minCut(state, index + 1, 1); // left subtree - adding 1 to vector
    minCut(state, index + 1, 0); // right subtree - adding 0 to vector

    return;
}


int main() {
    vector<int> state = {};
    minCut(state, -1, NULL);

    cout << MIN_COST << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to optimize the memory and avoid copies, you must use a passage by address (pointer or reference) and not by value as you do now in your `minCut`

Comment: With vector of size == 30, with only values 0/1, you might use instead `std::uint32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is effectively building a tree of paths, but you're using a `vector` to hold the nodes for each path.

```
           A
         /   \
        /     \
       B       C
      / \     / \
     D   E   F   G
```

This is the tree you're traversing.

But you're creating new vectors at every node, which contain the whole path up to that node. So as you're visiting node `G`, in your stack you have 3 `vector`s:

```
vector { A, C, G }
vector { A, C }
vector { A }
```

It should be clear how this is less efficient as you have noticed, but maybe seeing it this way hints at the correct efficient implementation.

The call stack *itself* holds the path to the root node. The stack when visiting `G` would be something like

```
minCut < visiting G >
minCut < visiting C >
minCut < visiting A >
```

In order to efficiently exploit this fact, make `minCut` pass the minimum amount of information. In this case we're talking about something linked-list like.

You have then two options that jump out:

1. Use `vector`, but:

   1. Pass it by reference.
   2. And you must then maintain it across calls, pushing and popping nodes to keep synchronized with the actual state.
2. Use an actual linked list. It should be easy to construct the `vector` by traversing pointers-to-parent-nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to pass `state` through each function call. This is called passing by reference and can be achieved like so:

```cpp
void minCut(vector<int>& state, int index, int nodeValue) { ...
```

This will result in the original `state` being referenced instead of copied each time the function is called.

For this to work correctly in the code you posted you will have to make some modifications, this is just the general concept.

Comment: this introduces a bug, since you have forget that `state` must be resorted to initial state, before returning from function. General concept is correct, so answer is just incomplete.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It's incorrect! Now you have the same state for the entire recursion and this makes for a different algorithm. You get a different result.

Comment: @bolov because an answer doesn't need to be complete or 100% complete to be useful.  In this case - it pointed the OP in the right direction; and that's all they needed.